# How can I programmatically add a file to a connections community files folder

Tags: ibm-sbt

From what I can tell from the IBMSBT API I can only upload a new file to My Files and I then share it with a community. I want to ultimately workflow the file and then lock it down for archival once approved.

I do not want it stored in anyone's MyFiles.

Ideal goal would be to upload it to a community with rights for everyone to work on it and once approved then reduce all access to reader only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may look at https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/pull/1653  it has no tests and was not merged in. also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912475/ibm-sbt-create-a-folder-in-a-community/27444275#27444275

Comment: I found that it is not exposed through the JavaScript API but it is in the Java API - fileService.uploadCommunityFile(...) - thanks Paul